How can a website make phones display a numeric keyboard with an enter key?
Modern browsers support the inputmode HTML attribute, allowing the website to instruct the device on what type of virtual keyboard to show. But choosing the numeric attribute causes many phones to display a keyboard with no enter key, making multiline input impossible.

The answer lies in the EnterKeyhint attribute MDN | Enter key hint
    <input type="text" inputmode="numeric" enterkeyhint="done">



